# What is the advantages of using binding attribute in JSF?

Tags: jsf

See the following code:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{jsfBean.name}" binding="#{jsfBean.htmlInputText}"/>
```

In the above example we are using the binding attribute to link with the server side bean property. I want to know what is the difference in using this attribute and not using this attribute.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With binding attribute you are mapping the **actual component and NOT the component's value**. For e.g the property in backing bean for your sample looks like below

```
UIInput htmlInputText= null;
...
public void setHtmlInputText(UIInput userNoComponent) {
  this.userNoComponent = userNoComponent;
}
public UIInput getHtmlInputText() {
  return userNoComponent;
}
```

**Binding a component instance** to a bean property has these advantages:

- The backing bean can programmatically
  modify component attributes.
- The backing bean can instantiate
  components rather than let the page
  author do so.

Find more details [in this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnatg.html)

Comment: I have another doubt. Is it correct implementation in the backing bean:public HtmlInputText getHtmlInputText() {
  return htmlInputText;
 }

 public void setHtmlInputText(HtmlInputText htmlInputText) {
  this.htmlInputText = htmlInputText;
 }

Comment: i believe yes. But I stick to UIInput unless you want to use the specific methods of the subclass

Comment: is it possible to set value by using binging a component instance as in value attiribute. When component render I want to set value in backing bean.