# Accessing JSF components tag attribute values from a backing bean

Tags: java, jsf, attributes, tags, web

I need to access a components tag attribute like:

```
<h:inputtext id="input_age"/>
```

from a backing bean, like:

```
public class UserInfo {
    String inputAgeId;
    public UserInfo() {
        inputAgeId = { /*code to access component tag attribute*/ }.getStyleClass();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
UIViewRoot view = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
```

You can then use [view.find("component_id")](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) to get the right component. Once you have the component, you can use [getAttributes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes%28%29) to get a `Map<String, Object>` with all the attributes of the component.

If you are accessing always the same compent, you can [bind it to the backing bean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4532955/1073063) instead.

Comment: Thank you Pablo, it was helpful and also the reference was great.

Comment: and also it was helpful too (http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnatg.html)

Comment: Is that the full ID with the prefixes of all enclosing naming containers?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I do getAttributes().get("class") hoping to get the class attributes of that tag I get something like *"class javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm"*. Furhter, the map is a very special construct that hides its keys, so I don't even know what other keys I could try.

Comment: @GyroGearloose I would suggest you to create a new question with some code examples.

Comment: I think I found my mistake. In jsf there is no "class" attribute but class="myClass" assignments are still rendered into the output-HTML without warning. By using name="myClass", it worked. The intend was to assign a type to some components, not a styleClass.