# How to get command link value(display name) from backing bean?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a p:commandLink in my xhtml with the value toggling between "Show"/"Hide".
Is there any way by which I can get the value of this commandlink from the backing bean?
I mean, I want to know what value the command link is showing currently i.e. Show/Hide?

Comment: instead you can have parameter passed in method call on commandLink.

Comment: What if you ever need to localize your webapp and thus provide button labels in different languages like so `value="#{msg['button.label']}"`? The need to know the button's value is then absolutely not a good solution as you'd have to take all those localized values into account as well. I recommend to reformulate your question to instead ask how to distinguish the pressed button if multiple buttons invoke the same method.

Comment: @BalusC-I agree with you and you have correctly understood my requirement.From thecommand link I am invoking and actionListener method in which I want to distinguish whether it is currently showing "Show"/"Hide".Because based on this,I have to show a popup dialog to the user. e.g. if it is "Show",I want the dialog to come.However if "Hide", I just want to bypass the bean code which invokes this dialog.FYI, i am showing the dialog from backend.Is it possible assuming that there is no other language support is there?

Comment: @PankajKathiriya-Could you please provide an example of that?e.g in my actionlistener method,I want to pass "Show" when the commandLink is reading as "Show"?

Answer (score 1):

To the point, the invoking component is just available in `ActionEvent` argument:

```
<h:commandLink id="show" value="Show it" actionListener="#{bean.toggle}" />
<h:commandLink id="hide" value="Hide it" actionListener="#{bean.toggle}" />
```

with

```
public void toggle(ActionEvent event) {
    UIComponent component = event.getComponent();
    String value = (String) component.getAttributes().get("value");
    // ...
}
```

However, this is a poor design. Localizable text should absolutely not be used as part of business logic.

Rather, *either* hook on component ID:

```
String id = (String) component.getId();
```

*or* pass a method argument ([EL 2.2 or JBoss EL required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/invoke-direct-methods-or-methods-with-arguments-variables-parameters-in-el/)):

```
<h:commandLink id="show" value="Show it" actionListener="#{bean.toggle(true)}" />
<h:commandLink id="hide" value="Hide it" actionListener="#{bean.toggle(false)}" />
```

with

```
public void toggle(boolean show) {
    this.show = show;
}
```

*or* even just call the setter method directly without the need for an additional action listener method:

```
<h:commandLink id="show" value="Show it" actionListener="#{bean.setShow(true)}" />
<h:commandLink id="hide" value="Hide it" actionListener="#{bean.setShow(false)}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As @BalusC suggested, your approach is not a good solution. But if you really want to do that, you can bind the component (`p:commandLink`) to your backingbean, as seen in [What is the advantages of using binding attribute in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532955/what-is-the-advantages-of-using-binding-attribute-in-jsf).
After the component was bound, you can access the `value` attribute from the `p:commandLink`.